# why postman doesn't get cross-origin block error?

Tags: javascript, security, postman

I've an API for auth, that works well with postman and returns JSON result, but after using that with JavaScript and fetch or axios I've cross-origin block in my browser.

But my question is not about cross-origin, I'm confused about difference between postman requests and browser requests ...

How does postman send request that doesn't receive access block errors? is there any difference for sending requests?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because `Postman` is a development tool and doesn't care about Same-origin policy.

It is actually the same for CURL..

CORS  and SOP are server-side configurations that clients decide to enforce or not... browser enforces it , postman not...

The server simply states the sites that are allowed cross origin access through the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in all its responses. It is up to the browser to respect this policy.

Some applications like postman, curl do not respect this policy, because they are meant to be used as developer tools, and as such it is expected that the people using these tools know what they’re doing.

Comment: ok, but how about security? I thought cross-origin is for handling security on server, but a hacker can use an application like postman to send a lot of requests.

Comment: I updated my answer. `I thought cross-origin is for handling security on server`  Server will only state with other site can make requests on this domain..that's all.... If you want to authenticate the client to the server you'll use the `Authorization` header.

Comment: @Alex It isn't a security feature for servers, it's a security feature for browsers.